# What is the meaning of the "if 0:" in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I found this piece of code:

```
if 0:
    somevariable = 1.0
    othervariable = 1.0
```

As far as I understand, 0 is always "FALSE", therefore the code never enters in the if and assigns the value to "somevariable" and "othervariable"

Does this actually make sense?

Comment: That code will never execute. It's probably to appease some type checker or static analysis tool, but it's definitely bizarre.

Comment: Some may introduce such an `if 0:` block to disable some statements. This allows to quickly enable that block again by removing the `if`. It seems something you could do temporarily while debugging, but it should not be there in production code.

Comment: Right.  It's similar to using `#if 0` and `#endif` in C or C++.  It's code I used before or might need later.

Answer (score 1):

"falsy" values like `0` or `''` evaluate to false for convenience and should not be used in the way described in your question. For example,

```
foo = 0
def bar():
    return foo + 1

if not foo:
    # I know that bar was not called
else:
    # I know bar was called
```

There is no need to check if `foo == 0`. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/truthy-vs-falsy-values-in-python/ shows all the possible types that can achieve this effect.

Hope this helps!